# RPM dependencies with localinstall

Tags: linux, dependencies, rpm

I need to install an rpm package on a system which has no internet access. So, let's say I already have needed dependencies. How do I install them only by running the main `rpm` package? Do they need to be in same directory as main rpm?

Answer (score 7):

If you have the files, it's just a mater of invoking `rpm` to install them. This can be done one at a time if you know which end of the stick to start from ... which files packages don't require the others to be installed first. If you don't know this or they are interdependent or you don't care you can just install them all at once.

```
rpm -Uvh package1.rpm package2.rpm [...]
```

If you downloaded or had everything you want to install isolated in a folder you could even just use `*.rpm`.

The `-U` argument is for upgrade. You could use `-I` for install, but if any of the packages already exist you will run into conflicts or duplicate installs. It's safe to just tell it to upgrade everything, any packages not installed will be added. The `-v` is for verbose so that you get some feedback about what's going on, and the `-h` just prints out the little hash mark status bars as it goes.